# In pylons how do I force user to download a file?

Tags: pylons

From a pylon controller action, instead of rendering a template, I want to send a file to the user to download. In languages like PHP, I can do the this thing like following. How can I do this in pylons?

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.exe\""); 
echo readfile($url);
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you searched the documentation? https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pylons-webframework/en/latest/ FYI, Pylons is in [maintenance-only mode](https://pylonsproject.org/about-pylons-framework.html)